# How can I abandon an IEnumerator without iterating to the end?

Tags: c#

Consider the following code, the first demonstrates that the "cleanup" executes when we're finished iterating over the IEnumerable of strings.  The second pass is what is causing me grief.  I need to be able abandon the IEnumerable before reaching the end, and then have the clean up code execute.  But if you run this you'll see that in the second pass the clean up never fires.

What is the preferred way of abandoning an IEnumerable like this?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // first pass
    foreach (String color in readColors())
        Console.WriteLine(color);

    // second pass
    IEnumerator<string> reader = readColors().GetEnumerator();
    if (reader.MoveNext())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader.Current);
        reader.Dispose();
    }
}
static IEnumerable<string> readColors()
{
    string[] colors = { "red", "green", "blue" };
    for (int i = 0; i < colors.Length; i++)
        yield return colors[i];

    Console.WriteLine("Cleanup goes here");
}
```

Comment: I may be missing something, or your example is over-simplified...but what cleanup do you ened to run at the end of the Enumeration in readColors? Seems like the GC should be able to handle things just fine itself.

Comment: If you have a custom collection, you could implement also the IDisposable as well?!.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to put the main part of your iterator method into a try..finally, with the cleanup code in the finally:

```
   public IEnumerable<string> readColors()
    {
        try
        {
            string[] colors = { "red", "green", "blue" };
            for (int i = 0; i < colors.Length; i++)
                yield return colors[i];
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cleanup goes here");
        }
    }
```

Remember that under the hood an iterator method causes a seperate class to be created, that implements `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerator`. By putting your cleanup in the finally block, it ends up in the generated class' `Dispose` method.

[**Edit:** (as pointed out in other answers) prefer a `using` statement over your approach of calling `Dispose` manually. I was assuming you'd done it like this just to highlight the issue under discussion, but it is worth pointing out anyway]

Comment: This is the correct answer, once you do this, you can simplify your second line to still use "foreach" rather than the more complicated code you have now.  Just do: foreach (String color in readColors()){ Console.WriteLine(color); break; }

Answer (score 4):

That's one way to abandon it. The reason that you are not seeing

```
Cleanup goes here
```

printed on the console is because the loop `for (int i = 0; i < colors.Length; i++)` never runs to completion. See below for how to force the cleanup code to execute.

Here's another way. This is the preferred pattern for using `IDisposable` objects in C#. This is preferred because this will cause `IEnumerator.Dispose` to be called even if an exception occurs.

```
using (IEnumerator<string> reader = readColors().GetEnumerator()) {
    reader.MoveNext();
    Console.WriteLine(reader.Current);
}
```

As for forcing the cleanup code you have to execute you can do the following:

```
static IEnumerable<string> readColors() {
    string[] colors = { "red", "green", "blue" };
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < colors.Length; i++) {
            yield return colors[i];
        }
    }
    finally {
        Console.WriteLine("Cleanup goes here");
    }
}
```

Comment: When I gave the downvote, there was only a couple of lines of answer which didn't seem to make much sense. Now you've clarified, I've removed it.

Comment: @Rob Levine: I clicked submit a little prematurely so fair enough. Thanks for coming back to comment.

Answer (score 1):

I think the preferred way of doing cleanup is by using `IDisposable`. In this case, your better of implementing your own `IEnumerable<string>` with a specific `IEnumerator<string>` and using the normal `Dispose` method. You get dispose for *free* when using `foreach`.

```
    class MyEnumerator : IEnumerator<string>
    {
        // ...
        #region IDisposable Members

        public void Dispose()
        {
            // do your cleanup here
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #endregion
        // ...
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to implement your own - the compiler will do it for you as long as you put the cleanup in a finally block.

Comment: Your probably correct, and for simple cases I think your answer is better.

Comment: P.S. that wasn't me that downvoted you - I was just pointing out you didn't need to implement your own. I think a downvote would have been a bit harsh - your answer is not *wrong* - there are just other ways of doing it that may be preferable in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {

    string[] colors = { "red", "green", "blue" };
    for (int i = 0; i < colors.Length; i++) {
     if(condition == true)
       break;
     yield return colors[i];
    }
}
finally {
    Console.WriteLine("Cleanup goes here");
}
```